# Cannot host more than one Wordpress site with docker and nginx as reverse proxy

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, docker-compose, digital-ocean

I am trying to host multiple sites on a single Digital Ocean VPS. I am using docker to achieve this. Each Wordpress site has its own database.

Using the docker-compose file of any of the two sites works fine and the site goes live. Adding a second does not work. (Navigating to the domain gives an nginx error of 'service temporarily unavailable')

I tried launching a static website from a container based on an apache image, and it does indeed work. So the nginx reverse proxy does successfully route traffic.

I am guessing that there is something more that I need to change between the two docker-compose files. Every tutorial or sample I've found stops after creating the first, and never actually shows a second Wordpress site being created.

Wordpress site 1:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     container_name: site1_db

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     expose:
       - 80
     restart: always
     environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: www.site1.com
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     container_name: site1_wp
volumes:
    db_data:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Wordpress site 2:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     container_name: site2_db

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     expose:
       - 80
     restart: always
     environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: www.site2.com
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
     container_name: site2_wp
volumes:
    db_data:

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

A network named nginx-proxy was created beforehand to link all the containers. I left out the details about the nginx instance as it uses the well known jwilder image and like I said, it does seem to work just fine.

Comment: Why do you use two `docker-compose` files? I think you need to combine your `docker-compose` files, `nginx proxy` to the another one. Also i think you have database issue because you have two database instances and it saves database to the same location.

Comment: No, each site is completely enclosed in its own directory with its own docker-compose file as well as mapped folders to the relevant containers

Comment: Could you check if two wordpress accessible not through `nginx proxy`?

Comment: add your nginx config

Comment: [jwilder nginx proxy](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy) does not need a config. it is automated nginx proxy.

Comment: Yes, that's correct @BukharovSergey, jwilder nginx proxy takes care of config. And no, the wordpress sites do not work simultaneously without the proxy either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It is two-fold:

1. The WORDPRESS_DB_HOST environmental variable should not be the service, but rather the container that it is referencing

Thus change:

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
```

to:

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: site1_db:3306
```

The same obviously goes for site2

2. The fix above still does not result in a working setup. When changing the database container to build from mariadb instead of mysql, it starts working! I have no idea in the slightest why this is true. Especially since the mysql instances can work on their own, but when running simultaneously, only mariadb works